# validation rule creation

Tags: validation-rule, profile, fields, required-field

Good day,

please support me in the following requirement. I have to create a validation rule on Contact object. It should be valid only for the profiles below. It should be for insertion of Phone or Mobile Phone by creation of the contact.

Here is my validation rule:

```
AND(
$Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - Standard User New" &&
$Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - CDA User" &&
$Profile.Name = "Barnes MS- External Sales Agent" &&
$Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - Marketing User",


ISBLANK(MobilePhone) &&
ISBLANK( Phone )
)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The first version was with OR instead of AND, but then it was valid for all profiles.

Answer (score 1):

VR to make sure they fill Both phone and mobile

```
AND(
   OR(
    $Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - Standard User New",
    $Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - CDA User",
    $Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - External Sales Agent",
    $Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - Marketing User")
  ),
  OR(
    ISBLANK(MobilePhone),
    ISBLANK( Phone )
  )
)
```

VR to make sure they fill EITHER Phone OR Mobile

```
AND(
   OR(
    $Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - Standard User New",
    $Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - CDA User",
    $Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - External Sales Agent",
    $Profile.Name = "Barnes MS - Marketing User")
  ),
  ISBLANK(MobilePhone),
  ISBLANK( Phone )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked

Comment: Hello again now when I am inserting Phone it still displays an error. What should be adjusted here?

Comment: The VR I created means you need to fill in BOTH Phone and Mobile to pass the VR. If you want just fill either phone or Mobile Phone, then the VR needs to change slightly by removing the OR

Comment: @user88574 updated the answer to show you the difference